# How can I make Local view round in Agora?

Tags: android, android-view, agora.io

I created customed RoundSurfaceView, and then,

```
val surfaceView = RtcEngine.CreateRendererView(baseContext) as RoundSurfaceView
```

and then, I got this error.

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: io.agora.rtc.video.ViEAndroidGLES20 cannot be cast to
```

I expect this kind of shape.

[image]

How can I make it? I also tried with custom RoundFrameLayout. But it didn't work.

Comment: Cannot be cast to... what? If you get this error on the line where you initialise `surfaceView`, make sure to check how you can get `RoundSurfaceView` from `ViEAndroidGLES20` (if that is indeed possible). It does not seem to return the object you expect it to.

Comment: Well, I don't how ViEAndroidGLES20 works under the hood, Agora SDK does it. And RoundSurfaceView is a custom view that inherited SurfaceView. @PrimožIvančič

Comment: Please share xml of your local view

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `SurfaceView` inside a `CardView` and add corner radius to it.